# MemGrapg connection to PowerBI / Tableau

Tags: memgraphdb

Cam memgraph connect to any of the standard visualization products such as PowerBI , Tableau. N4j seems to have recently launch a enterprise version of PowerBI connector.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, Memgraph does not have an ODBC connection to connect to such sources. However, it is in the works to make visualization products as one of the destinations for Memgraph analytics.

The thing is that PowerBI can connect to a streaming dataset and accept incoming data while making ad-hoc dynamic visualizations. This is not the same though as making queries to static data to the database and visualizing it as capabilities of streaming dataset is a bit low on the PowerBI side.

Haven't yet checked Tableau, so no info on that side.

For concrete use cases and technical help, try checking their Discord page at https://discord.com/invite/memgraph